# No item exists at ... It may have been deleted or renamed by another user .. for some items only?

Tags: list, error

I crated a webpart page and added a SPD listformwebpart in display mode for a particular list.

All day yerterday I called the page and pass it the ?ID= query string and itworked great. It still works great for the items I had created.

This morning I added a workflow where I email the URL to the page with the ID dynamically on it. Any items I added today give me the error:
***No item exists at ... It may have been deleted or renamed by another user***

All items from yesterday work fine on that page... ????

I was demoing the solution and was completely at a loss to explain this.

I checked and there is no Item security. 
I can pull up the suspect items using the native list Display page.
I show up as the creator and last modifier
My workflow is NOT making any changes to the list .. only sending a url to my page.

Same URL with only the ID different..Some items work.. some don't.. Any explanation for this?

==
**UPDATE: I created a brand new page with no code. Just the listform and the problem persist with it where new items do not display.**

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the ID as the query string in Custom Page, other than SharePoint View pages. Because, SharePoint try to render the items from Library based on ID, where your page is there.

Soln: Always use different query string (other than ID) to refer the List Item ID in your custom Page.

Answer (score 1):

Change the name of the query string parameter from `ID` to something like `CustomID`. SharePoint uses `ID` internally to identify documents and pages on the server. See [support kb972225](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/972225) for full details. The article says that it applies to SP2007 but I had the same issue with SP2010.